# PlayIntegrity response decryption got javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT

Tags: android, jwe, jose4j, google-play-integrity-api

I am trying to decode the response from Google Play Integrity in Android client. I followed the steps from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-locally). Decoding from server works however decoding locally results in this exception:

```
stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[18]@28628}
 0 = {StackTraceElement@28631} "org.jose4j.jwe.SimpleAeadCipher.decrypt(SimpleAeadCipher.java:109)"
 1 = {StackTraceElement@28632} "org.jose4j.jwe.AesGcmContentEncryptionAlgorithm.decrypt(AesGcmContentEncryptionAlgorithm.java:79)"
 2 = {StackTraceElement@28633} "org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.decrypt(JsonWebEncryption.java:211)"
 3 = {StackTraceElement@28634} "org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getPlaintextBytes(JsonWebEncryption.java:79)"
 4 = {StackTraceElement@28635} "org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getPlaintextString(JsonWebEncryption.java:72)"
 5 = {StackTraceElement@28636} "org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getPayload(JsonWebEncryption.java:87)"
 ...
 8 = {StackTraceElement@28639} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)"
 12 = {StackTraceElement@28643} "android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)"
 13 = {StackTraceElement@28644} "java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)"
 14 = {StackTraceElement@28645} "android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)"
 15 = {StackTraceElement@28646} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)" 
 16 = {StackTraceElement@28647} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)"
 17 = {StackTraceElement@28648} "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)"
```

Code:

```
val integrityManager = IntegrityManagerFactory.create(context)
val integrityTokenResponse: Task<IntegrityTokenResponse> =
    integrityManager.requestIntegrityToken(
        IntegrityTokenRequest.builder()
            .setCloudProjectNumber(GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER)
            .setNonce(nonce)
            .build())

val playIntegrityResponse = Tasks.await(integrityTokenResponse)
val integrityToken = playIntegrityResponse.token()

val base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey = "..."
val base64OfEncodedVerificationKey = "..."

 // base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey is provided through Play Console.
val decryptionKeyBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey, Base64.DEFAULT)

// Deserialized encryption (symmetric) key.
val decryptionKey: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(
    decryptionKeyBytes,
    0,
    decryptionKeyBytes.size, //AES_KEY_SIZE_BYTES,
    "AES" //AES_KEY_TYPE
)

// base64OfEncodedVerificationKey is provided through Play Console.
val encodedVerificationKey: ByteArray =
    Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedVerificationKey, Base64.DEFAULT)

// Deserialized verification (public) key.
val verificationKey: PublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
    .generatePublic(X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedVerificationKey))

val jwe: JsonWebEncryption =
    JsonWebStructure.fromCompactSerialization(integrityToken) as JsonWebEncryption
jwe.key = decryptionKey

// This also decrypts the JWE token.
val compactJws: String = jwe.payload

val jws: JsonWebSignature =
    JsonWebStructure.fromCompactSerialization(compactJws) as JsonWebSignature
jws.key = verificationKey

// This also verifies the signature.
val payload: String = jws.payload <!-- "org.jose4j.lang.JoseException: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT"
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few days ago. And then I read [Google's Integrity API setup documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup). Since you're using manual decryption. It is important to notice that your application should be on Google Play if you're to manually decrypt your token, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#self-manage-encryption) says:

> To manage and download your response encryption keys, you must use the Play Console, and your app must be available on Google Play.

I think your application is not currently on Google Play. In that case, you can let Google manage your response encryption, which is default and suggested.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: App released to internal testing (not public) nevertheless downloaded from Google Play so I believe this will be considered as "available on Google Play".